# Access a property of a class that mainly handles a list of objects from any of these objects. (vb.net)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to access a property of a class (let's call it 'A') that is built to handle a list of some other class (call it 'B'), from any 'B' member. But I don't want this property to be shared (static) so any instance of 'A' can have a different value of this property, and any 'B' accesses the property of the 'A' it belongs to.

eg

```
**class A**
private Items as list (of B)
...
...
public property ThisProperty() as Integer

**end class**



**class B**
...
public function UseThisProperty() as string
If ThisProperty=1 then 
return "this"
elseif ThisProperty=2 then 
return "other"
else
return "sth else"
end function

**End class**
```

I don't know how and if that is possible, but any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Are the Bs "owned" by the As? Do they control the creation, destruction and membership? If not, what's to stop a `B` from being added to multiple `A`s? Or belonging to none?

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to solve this. However, the solution highly depends on the context and questions like *Who creates object A/B?, what is the lifecycle of A/B?, who is the client of A/B? How coupled are A/B?*. 
Nevertheless here are some solutions:

```
Public Class A
    Public Property ThisProperty() As Integer
End Class
```

**Inject object A into B via constructor**. Helpful if A and B are closely coupled and if it´s not a drawback that they are. Also when creating B A must alreday exist:

```
Public Class B
    Private _a As A
    Public Sub New(a As A)
        _a = a
    End Sub
    Public Function UseThisProperty() As String
        If _a.ThisProperty = 1 Then
            Return "this"
        ElseIf _a.ThisProperty = 2 Then
            Return "other"
        Else
            Return "sth else"
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

**Inject just the value of `A.ThisProperty` into B via constructor**. Helpful to decouple A and B and there is only one(few) property which is used by B:

```
Public Class B
    Private _aThisProperty As Integer
    Public Sub New(thisProperty As Integer)
        _aThisProperty = thisProperty
    End Sub

    Public Function UseThisProperty() As String
        If _aThisProperty = 1 Then
            Return "this"
        ElseIf _aThisProperty = 2 Then
            Return "other"
        Else
            Return "sthelse"
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

**Inject A when calling B.UseThisProperty**. This is helpful if there is a class C which decouples A and B:

```
Public Class D
    Public Function UseThisProperty(a As A) As String
        If a.ThisProperty = 1 Then
            Return "this"
        ElseIf a.ThisProperty = 2 Then
            Return "other"
        Else
            Return "sth else"
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

**Inject A into B via public setter**. This is helpful if A is not yet determined when creating object B:

```
Public Class B
    Public Property a As A
    Public Function UseThisProperty() As String
        If a.ThisProperty = 1 Then
            Return "this"
        ElseIf a.ThisProperty = 2 Then
            Return "other"
        Else
            Return "sth else"
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

There are other soltion like a `Mediator` class which could decouple A and B completely etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer, however B isn't aware of A's existence, it can or can not "belong" to A, and any 'B' should be able to be moved from one instance of A to another. So the constructor solution is not what I was looking for... 
The value of ThisProperty should be evaluated on the fly by any B, could change its value obviously, and so, B would have to alter its behavior... I know I am asking for too much here.. I hope a convenient solution still exists... Thank you again!

Comment: You have to extract your code in `UseThisProperty` from class B and put it in another decoupled class. You say B isn´t aware of A - what is good - but you need some kind of a Mediator class which handles the relationships between A and B. This is getting worse as you wrote that B can change state of A. This can only be done via an indirect class since B does not know A. Create two interfaces for A and B, where IA has the needed property. In the Mediator class take one instance of IA and IB and give back the results. Create another function to let IB change the property of IA. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much again, yes, a mediator class should do the job.  I will look it up and try to implement it to solve this issue.  Have a nice day!

Comment: If you have any further questions while implementing this approach don´t hesitate to ask again. Cheers.